# is this c# array of array the same as this jquery array or array

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, arrays

This is my c# code, where `InBoundtable` is a datatable

```
DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
            var result = (from row in InBoundtable.AsEnumerable()
                         group row by row.Field <string> ("Date") into grp
                         select new {
                             AbandonCalls = grp.Sum((r) => Double.Parse(r["AvgAbandonedCalls"].ToString())),
                             Date = ((DateTime.Parse(grp.Key)) - epoch).TotalMilliseconds
                         }).ToList();

            double[][] finalArray = new double[result.Count][];
            for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++) {
                double[] tempArrayDoubel = new double[2];
                tempArrayDoubel[0] = result[i].Date;
                tempArrayDoubel[1] = result[i].AbandonCalls;
                finalArray[i] = tempArrayDoubel;
            }
```

I return the `final array` using this code:

```
string jsonformatstring = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(finalArray, Formatting.Indented);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(jsonformatstring);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

I call that web service like this:

```
$.getJSON(webServiceUrl,
  { fromDate: valFrom, toDate: valTo, sliceNumber:sliceNumber })
   .done(function (result) {

       console.log(result);
```

The result on the console is this:
[image]

#### My question

:
is that format in the image the same as this format:

```
d3 = [
        [1325376000000, 650], [1328054400000, 450], [1330560000000, 150], [1333238400000, 200],
        [1335830400000, 150]
    ];
```

?

#### Update 1

This is the result of expanding the array in jquery 
[image]

Comment: Uhm, maybe show us the content of result variable not just a picture? Use JSON.stringify on the result and give it to us as text. If I must judge by this picture they probably are in the same format..

Comment: The format is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is the same format assuming the Array[2] are of the format [Number, Number]. And from what I can see of the C# code it is generating the format you want.